# How to Update Node.js in docker container? Laravel / Sail developemnt

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, npm

I have been getting warnings when I run npm run dev

```
sail npm run dev
npm does not support Node.js v15.10.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

The process runs okay. laravel mix is doing its job, creating the app.css, etc.  However, having took notice, I decided to try to update Node.js in the docker container, so I did the following.

```
sail root-shell
apt update
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm --version
   0.38.0
nvm install 16.17.0
nvm ls             
->     v16.17.0
         system
default -> 16.17.0 (-> v16.17.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v16.17.0) (default)
stable -> 16.17 (-> v16.17.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.17.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.20.0 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.17.0
```

So it appears that Node.js is indeed updated to the latest stable version. at least in the sail root-shell.  I stopped the docker container using the desktop app, then restarted it.

However, when I then issue the sail npm --version command, the response is the same, that is:

```
npm does not support Node.js v15.10.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
```

If I update the Node.js version in the sail root-shell, why doesn't the "sail npm --version" command recognize that the Node.js version has been updated?

As added info, i used the terminal in php storm.  before invoking sail commands I issue

```
alias sail='bash vendor/bin/sail'
```

then I can use the shorter "sail npm -- version"  syntax.

Signed confused.

Comment: You'd almost never install software in a running container like that; those changes will get lost as soon as the container is recreated.  I'd also avoid version managers like `nvm` in a Docker context (along with non-standard shell commands like `source` or `alias`).  Does your image have a Dockerfile that you can include in the question?  Can you install Node from `nodejs.org` without using `nvm`?

Comment: thank you.  I think I get it.   I think the culprit is that I am using the image "sail-8.0./app".  I believe that image contains the versions of NPM and Node that are, in a sense, unmovable.  I have not looked to see if there is perhaps a later version of this image. And will do so.`(https://laravel.com/docs/sail)
version: '3'
services:
laravel.test:
build:
   context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
 args:
   WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: sail-8.0/app`

Comment: It looks like you already have a Dockerfile; can you do something like `RUN curl -LO https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.17.0/node-v16.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz` in the Dockerfile to download the Node version you need?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  Not sure.  But you have put me on a good path.  Thanks for your thoughts.   I am a docker rookie so I am hesitant to run the curl command in the docker compose file.  I suppose if I mess up, I can just take it out and things will still be hunky dory (whatever that means!  wonder where the saying came from) https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hunky-dory.html.

Answer (score 3):

Well, It pays to read the documentation!  Laravel Sail installs Node Version 16 by default.  If you want another version you need to make a simple change to the docker.yml file.

[Change Node Versions in Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#sail-node-versions)

```
build:
    args:
        WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        NODE_VERSION: '14'
```